# the out put of time showing in negative ex:(-3:45)

Tags: postgresql

data which are using:

```
agent_accepted_date : 2020-06-28 20:42:53.584781 
submitted_date: 2020-06-28 16:47:21.384827-04 
reviewer_accepted_date: 2020-06-28 20:48:50.287589 
reviewed_date: 2020-06-28 16:49:32.670873-04
```

same as review also instead of accept date replacing

```
(case 

     when ptra.submitted_date is null then
                  DATE_PART('day', now()::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp)*24+
                  DATE_PART('hour', now()::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp) ||':'||
                  DATE_PART('min', now()::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp)
                         
     when  ptra.submitted_date is not null then 
           DATE_PART('day',submitted_date::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp)*24+
           DATE_PART('hour', submitted_date::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp) ||':'||
           DATE_PART('min', submitted_date::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp)
           end) as elapsed_id,
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i am trying to getting date from above calcuclations but the result getting negative time ...-3hrs:20mnts like this

Answer (score 0):

> submitted_date: 2020-06-28 16:47:21.384827-04

'-04' at the end indicates the timezone (GMT-4h, Quebec time). Lack of that part in *agent_accepted_date* means it's missing the time zone information. [now()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is an alias for current_timestamp() which returns the time at the beginning of current transaction in the time zone of your database which might be different.

Missing/mismatched timezones might result in negative intervals - if you strip the timezone information from two timestamps representing the exact same moment, but one collected in GMT+00, the other in GMT+02, you'll get negative 2 hours difference. Here's an experiment:

```
select localtimestamp(6)-(localtimestamp(6) at time zone 'gmt+02')::timestamp as difference;
 difference
------------
 -02:00:00
(1 row)
```

To track down those differences you can check your timezone as follows:

```
select current_setting('timezone');
```

And once you determine where your timestamps come from, you can [cast your timestamps to different timezones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) like so:

```
select your_timestamp at time zone 'your_target_timezone';
```

And you can see what timezones are supported on your database like this:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names;
```

Also, that case statement could be replaced with [coalesce()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). Here's a shortened example [casting your input timestamps from their origin timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) to your database timezone:

```
DATE_PART('day', coalesce(submitted_date::timestamp, current_timestamp()) - agent_accepted_date::timestamp at time zone 'their origin timezone' at time zone (select current_setting('timezone')))*24+
DATE_PART('hour', coalesce(submitted_date::timestamp, current_timestamp()) - agent_accepted_date::timestamp at time zone 'their origin timezone' at time zone (select current_setting('timezone'))) ||':'||
DATE_PART('min', coalesce(submitted_date::timestamp, current_timestamp()) - agent_accepted_date::timestamp at time zone 'their origin timezone' at time zone (select current_setting('timezone')))
    as elapsed_id
```

You could further shorten it defining the entire timestamp subtraction in a separate [WITH statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) and then just referring to it three times instead of copying over the entire operation each time you need to extract a different part of the timestamp. Since you end up getting a text type (you concatenate hours to minutes, separating them with a colon), you can also look into just [extracting a substring](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html).

Keep in mind you still need to determin what time zones the submitted_date came from. Your example shows -3:45 difference so I would guess the timestamps lacking the timezone are in one of these:

```
 select * from pg_timezone_names where utc_offset::text like '%:45:%' or utc_offset::text like '%:15:%';
      name       | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
-----------------+--------+------------+--------
 Pacific/Chatham | +1245  | 12:45:00   | f
 Australia/Eucla | +0845  | 08:45:00   | f
 NZ-CHAT         | +1245  | 12:45:00   | f
 Asia/Katmandu   | +0545  | 05:45:00   | f
 Asia/Kathmandu  | +0545  | 05:45:00   | f
```

While your database is in a timezone a few hours away from one of them.